# element with width 100% and padding

Tags: jquery

how can you make an element with width 100% and padding fit inside another element without changing the width of the parent?

```
var inp = $('<input type="text" style="padding:4px; width:100%" />')
      .appendTo('<div style="width:200px"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `width: 100%` and `padding: 4px` together in this case. The element will always be **8px** wider than its parent. You have to go with pixel values for your input element. In your case it would be `width: 192px`.

The box model always (except some older IE versions) adds the padding (and border) to the elements width. So if the width is **100%** each pixel of horizontal padding will make the element wider than its parent.

You could fake your input style this way by achieving the 100% width with padding.

```
<div style="width:200px">
    <div style="border: 1px solid blue; background: #fff">
        <div style="padding:2px 4px">
            <input type="text" style="display:block; width:100%; border:0; padding:0" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`input` elements are `display: inline` by default. Make them `display: block` if you want the `width: 100%` to work.

Comment: but how can you then have more inputs side by side if you the total width of the elements to determine the width of the parent element?

Comment: Good point, but not really an answer to his question, or am I wrong?

Comment: @clarkk: if you want them side by side then you don't want them to be `100%` in width, or am I wrong? You can always use `float: left` to have blocking elements side by side.